# cordova google plus plugin and google map not working together

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic3

I want to use both Google-map plugin and cordova google plus plugin (google login) together in my ionic 3 app. But google plus plugin not working with google map plugin. Google plus plugin not showing any error, but simply not working. when i remove google map plugin, then google plus plugin is working fine. how do i use both plugin together in my app? please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: there was a similar issue form last week and it seem he fixed it by updating Cordova to 8.0.0 and cordova-android to 7.1.1

Comment: I'm already using those versions but still not working. Getting no errors but not working

Comment: If you share your project files on github, I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a google play services incompatibilities. First you have to make sure to use the same for google maps and google plus plugins. So you have to go to the config.xml and specify that like adding the PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION variable. For example:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="^5.3.2">
        <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="15.0.1" />
</plugin>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="^2.4.6">
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="sjdsdksdkjs" />
        <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="15.0.1" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
</plugin>
```

Then you remove and add again the platform, or just go to /platforms/android/project.properties and change all the versions of the "play-services" to 15.0.1 for example.

```
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
```

Hope that this can help you, work for me.